# Bash scripting and escaping

Tags: bash

I'm having some trouble with this bash script, which I intend to use as a startup script for a web server running nginx+unicorn.

```
DAEMON='/bin/su - deployer -c "/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/unicorn -c /home/deployer/apps/myapp/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D"'
```

Error:

> /bin/su: invalid option -- 'E'

I need to run the script as the user deployer, but I am uncertain how to pass all my command to /bin/su. I'm sure this is a simple escaping error but after trying several different ways of escaping it but I am just not getting this right. Thanks.

Comment: why are you assigning the whole su command chain to a variable? You'll have to use `eval "$DAEMON"` to get it to work, and everyone hates evaling code, (its a big security risk). Good luck.

Comment: It was the first thing I thought of when I noticed I have to run this init script as the user 'deployer'. Better ways to do it are welcome.

Comment: Why is the command in a variable? The implicit suggestion here for a better solution is to not put the command in a variable. See also http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/050

Comment: @tripleee Ah. I didn't get it. Good idea! In fact, that link right there is what I needed to read all along but never found on my own. Write your comment as an answer and I'll accept it.

Comment: @shellter deserves the credit here really. Glad I could help clarify his (?) point, though.

Comment: @tripleee : thanks, but I was too lazy to find a link to explain the issue, you did, so plase go ahead and post your reply. Good luck to all!

Comment: The wiki link you posted is great! I always looked for exactly that kind of FAQ, I'm going to bookmark it, thanks a lot!

Comment: @tripleee shellter wants you to post the answer, so go ahead. :)

Answer (score 2):

Try to separate sudo options and command with `--`

```
DAEMON='/bin/su - deployer -c -- "/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/unicorn -c /home/deployer/apps/myapp/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D"'
```

Answer (score 1):

There are no variables in the command, so you can simply put it in a function:

```
daemon() {
    /bin/su - deployer -c "/home/deployer/.rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.3-p125/bin/unicorn -c /home/deployer/apps/myapp/current/config/unicorn.rb -E production -D"
}
```